# What should a subset of prime numbers $S$ fullfill for the product of its elements plus one to equal another prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

If we let $S$ be any subset of the set of prime numbers $P$, for some S, the product of the elements of $S$ plus 1 is, in fact, another prime number:

$$\exists S \subset P:[\prod_{i=1}^{|S|} S_i] + 1 \in P$$

Here are some examples to the aforementioned claim:

$$ S = \{ 2, 3, 5 \} \Rightarrow 2 \times 3 \times 5 + 1 =  31 \in P$$
$$ S = \{ 2, 5, 7 \} \Rightarrow 2 \times 5 \times 7 + 1 =  71 \in P$$

However, there are also some cases for which the claim doesn't hold. The counterexample is as follows:

$$ S = \{ 3, 5 \} \Rightarrow 3 \times 5 + 1 =  16 \notin P$$

I was wondering what properties S should have in order to comply with this claim. One of them can be understood from the counterexample, which is that $S$ must contain 2, as:

$$2\notin S \Rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{|S|} S_i \bmod 2 = 1 $$

What are some other things $S$ has to fulfill for the claim to be true? Can they be proven?

Comment: The condition you told can be seen to be false by taking $S = \{2,13\}$ as $2\times 13 + 1 = 27 \notin P$. I mean that condition does not guarentee that $P$ is as required.

Comment: Equivalently you seek primes $\,P\,$ with $\,P-1\,$ squarefree (with prime factor set $S)\ \ $

Comment: Yes, that is true. This means there are some other factors that makes $S$ true for the claim. Can you think of any which would suit this example?

Comment: @usuyus22 Consider the point Bill Dubuque made. :)

Comment: @Rick Right, that's another way to say it

Comment: It's [OEIS A039787](https://oeis.org/A039787) $\ 2, 3, 7, 11, 23, 31, 43, 47, 59, 67, 71, 79, 83, 103, 107, 131, 139, 167, 179, 191\ldots$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153109/242) for their density.

Comment: See also [OEIS A075432](https://oeis.org/A075432) = Primes with no squarefree neighbors (non-Euclidean primes).

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classic prime $N-1$ test. 
Set $P = p_1p_2\dots p_k + 1$ equal to the product of the primes $+ 1$, then if you can find an integer $a$ such that 
$$ a^{P-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{P}$$
and
$$ a^{\frac{P-1}{p_i}} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{P}\quad i=1,\dots,k $$
then $P$ is prime. 
If $a^{P-1} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{P}$ for any $a$ then $P$ is composite.