# Convergence of the Fourier Transform of the Prime $\zeta$ Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

I think I found a way to write the truncated Prime $\zeta$ function like this:
$$
P_x(s)=\sum_{p<x} \frac{1}{p^s} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}
\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\left[
{\rm li}(t^{\frac zn-s})
\right]^{x}_2
\tag{7},
$$
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341) for confirmation (or please correct me if I'm wrong)!

My next step of interest would be to know something about its Fourier Transform.

**EDIT, containing some fresh ideas, changing the flavour of the question**

The answer seems trivial when you look at the lhs of $(7)$, set $s\to is$ and rewrite it as
$$
P_x(is)=\sum_{p<x} \frac{1}{p^{is}}
= \sum_{p<x} \exp(-is\ln p)
$$
to see that spectrum is (remember that $x$ is fixed)
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty P_x(is)\exp(i2\pi s \omega) ds
&=&\sum_{p<x} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-is\ln p) \exp(i2\pi s \omega)ds \\
&=&\sum_{p<x} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\biggr(is(2\pi  \omega-\ln p)\biggr) ds\\
&=&\sum_{p<x}\delta( \omega -\ln p)\tag{8}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

But when I take Fourier's integral deeper into the ${\bf r}\text{abbit's } {\bf h}\text{ole} {\bf s}$  of $(7)$, I'll get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\color{green}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds e^{i2\pi s \omega}}P_x(is) 
&=&
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}
\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\underbrace{
\left(
\color{green}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds e^{i2\pi s \omega}}
\left[{\rm li}(t^{\frac zn-s})
\right]^{x}_2
\right)
}_{\uparrow}
\tag{9}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

But as robjohn pointed out in the [comments to my (attempt of an) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283142/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-this-integral-logarithm/283343#comment618386_283343) this integral is unlikely to converge.
But we have $(8)$.

> Does this mean that the sum of sums,
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}
> \sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}$,
>   forces convergence?

---

**OLD ATTEMPT**

I tried the following:

1. Write it down for one of the summands ${\rm li}(x^{y})$ with $y=\frac zn-s\in \Bbb C$:
   $$
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y){\rm li}(x^{y}) dy \tag{*}
   $$
2. Use partial integration $\int u' v = [uv]-\int uv'$ to get
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y){\rm li}(x^{y}) dy&=&
   \left[\frac{\exp(2\pi i\omega y)}{2\pi i\omega}{\rm li}(x^{y})\right]_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(2\pi i\omega y)x^y\log x}{\log(x^{y})} dy\\
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$
3. I'm not sure about the $[\cdots]_{-\infty}^\infty$-parts. I hope it vanishes. Is this true?
4. My next idea was to Taylor expand  $\exp(2\pi i\omega y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi i \omega)^k}{k!}y^k$ to get:
   $$
   -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi i \omega)^k}{k!} \int_{-\infty}^\infty   \frac{y^k x^y\log x}{\log(x^{y})} dy
   $$
   Our good friend Wolfram can help with the last integral ($x$ and $y$ interchanged for the sake of simpler inputs for W|A!!!) in an indefinite form for fixed $k=$ [$1$](http://tinyurl.com/ap88h2d), [$2$](http://tinyurl.com/ashf6fo) or [$3$](http://tinyurl.com/ajox5g9), but I think I'm kind of led astray.

Even with an analytical expression for that I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Would it be better to expand ${\rm li}(x^y)$?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

*This was my first attempt to answer the old question. It might be wrong, but I'll keep it due to the valuable comments below:*

Use ${\rm li}(z)={\rm Ei}(\ln z)$ to get:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y){\rm li}(x^{y}) dy&=&
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y){\rm Ei}(y\ln x) dy\\ 
&=&\left[\frac{\exp(2\pi i\omega y)}{2\pi i\omega}{\rm Ei}(y\ln x)\right]_{-\infty}^{\phantom{-}\infty}
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y)\frac{\exp(y\ln x)}{y} dy\\ 
&=&\left[\frac{\exp(2\pi i\omega y)}{2\pi i\omega}{\rm Ei}(y\ln x)\right]_{-\infty}^{\phantom{-}\infty}
-\frac{{\rm Ei}\biggr(y(2\pi i \omega-\ln x)\biggr)}{2\pi i\omega},
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/a3aqxcm) helped a bit. Assuming a vanishing bracket, this gives a nice result...

Comment: How can $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(2\pi i\omega y)\frac{\exp(y\ln x)}{y} dy$ converge? Whether $\ln(x)$ is positive or negative, one side of the integral should diverge.

Comment: @robjohn so you say that the Fourier Transform doesn't exist? How else can I get some information about the periodic properties of $li(\cdot)$?

Comment: That doesn't follow, unless you know that the bracket quantity is finite, which it isn't. $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ blows up like $e^x/x$ as $x\to+\infty$. That is, the final answer above is $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: Isn't the bracket $\infty-0$ since $\lim_{y\to-\infty} Ei(y)=0$? What if I restricted my region of interest to let's say $y<y_\max$ by using some kind of boxing (is this the right word...?) function?

Comment: Yes, the bracket is $\infty$ and the integral is $\infty$. Adding some cutoff function can strongly affect the Fourier Transform, but it might work.

Comment: @robjohn What if $s$ is pure imaginary? $\rm Ei(\cdot)$ wouldn't blow then as you can see [here](http://tinyurl.com/be3aa7s). Maybe this post ["Why is $\pi$ the Limit of the Absolute Value of the Prime $\zeta$ Function?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/161346/19341) might also be related...

Comment: @robjohn Since I started out with $P_\color{red}x(\color{blue}s)=\sum_{p<\color{red}x} \frac{1}{p^s}$ the cut off is quite obvious.The frequency range is $[\pm \ln x]$. Would this justify to set the limits of the integral accordingly? I'm unsure since this is the range of the frequencies $\omega$. Further it's not $x$ I'm varying, it's $y=\frac zn -s$...it's pretty difficult to keep that all in the RAM and you would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I recently derived the commonly known asymptotic approximation for $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/286573). Beyond that, I believe I am out of my depth in these matters.

Comment: @robjohn thanks anyway. Can recommend a book or something to read on that topic?