# Why $\zeta (1/2)=-1.4603545088...$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

I saw $\zeta (1/2)=-1.4603545088...$ in this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html). But how can that be? Isn't $\zeta (1/2)$ divergent since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+..>\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+..$ ?

Comment: You're confusing between the summation $\sum_{n>0}\frac1{n^s}$ and the $\zeta$-regularization of the sum.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is actually defined for _every_ complex number except for $s=1$. The series for $\zeta$ doesn't always converge, but the series isn't exactly the definition of $\zeta$.

Comment: There is a formula for this number at https://oeis.org/A059750
The user anon here at math overflow knows how to explain it. I wrote the formula in the chat room and anon then referred to this answer of his:http://math.stackexchange.com/a/113837/8530

Comment: By the way, $\zeta(1/2)=(\sqrt2+1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}$, if you want some converging sequence that defines it.

Answer (score 21):

$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n} n^{-s}$ when that makes sense. But $\zeta$ has an "analytic continuation" to much of the rest of the complex plane.

Consider the equality:

$$\frac{1}{1-z} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$$

The right side only converges and equals the left side when $|z|<1$.

But complex analysis has this awesome feature - that any function has at most one analytic continuations to the regions where it is not already defined.[*] So $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is the *only* analytic continuation of the right side for complex $z$.

The same is true for the $\zeta$ function. We first define it for $s$ where the real part is greater than one. And then we find a way to continue that function for other values of $s$.

The heart of the extension of $\zeta$, at least to $1/2$, is that, for $s>1$:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^s} =\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^s} - 2\sum_{n} \frac{1}{(2n)^s}=\sum_{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

The right side is defined for any $s\in(0,1]$, since it is the sum of an alternating decreasing sequence. (It converges for other $s$ with $\mathrm{Re}\,s >0$, but it isn't 100% obvious looking at it that this is true.[**])

This lets us extend $\zeta(s)$ to $s\in(0,1)$:

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}} \sum_n \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

This is equal to our original definition when $\mathrm{Re }\,s>1$.

So $$\zeta(1/2) = \frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Computing for $M=200,000,000$ terms of this sum I get:

$$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=1}^M \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}\approx -1.460269$$

This series converges very slowly.

---

[*] Just for clarity: If you have a path-connected open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ and $V\subseteq U$ so that $V$ contains an bounded infinite subset, and a function $f:V\to\mathbb C$, then there is at most one analytic $g:U\to \mathbb C$ so that $g(v)=f(v)$ for $v\in V$.

[**] We have a general theorem:

> Given a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_i\}$ such that $a_i\to 0$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_{2i-1}+a_{2i})$$ converges, then so does $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i$.

In this case, let $a_i=\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^s}$. Then we'll use that $(1-x)^s=1-xs+o(x)$:

$$\begin{align}a_{2i-1}+a_{2i} &=\frac{(2i)^s-(2i-1)^s}{(2i(2i-1))^s}\\
&=\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^s}{(2i-1)^s}\\
&=\frac{\frac{s}{2i} + o\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)}{(2i-1)^s}\\
&=O\left(\frac{1}{i^{s+1}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: "any function has at most one analytic continuations to the regions where it is not always defined" ... perhaps you need to reconsider...

Comment: Yeah, meant "already." And technically, it isn't true for disconnected regions, I was trying to not get into the nitty-gritty about analytic continuations, but may have oversimplified.

Comment: In a certain sense, it can also fail for non-simply connected regions.  Such as extending $z^{1/2}$ from the right half-plane to the punctured plane.  So, in particular, some work must be done when extending $\zeta(z)$ to make sure it is unique.

Comment: No, there is no way to analytically extend $z^{1/2}$ to the punctured plane. Which agrees with my statement. @GEdgar

Comment: I recognize what you are saying - that the uniqueness is up to the region in which you want to define. I was not trying to be formal - the OP might or might not have the background for a detailed description of what that means.

Answer (score 4):

According to Gradshteyn-Ryzhik (1980) 9.513.1, we have
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-s})\Gamma(s)}
\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}\ \text{d}t}{e^t+1},
\qquad (\text{Re}\ s>0)
$$
which is rewritten by partial integration (because $\text{Re}\ s>0$) as
$$
\zeta(s)=
\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-s})\Gamma(s+1)}
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^s\ e^t\ \text{d}t}{(e^t+1)^2}.
$$
By changing the integration variable $t=2x$, we obtain
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac{2^{s-1}}{(1-2^{1-s})\Gamma(s+1)}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s\ \text{d}x}{\text{cosh}^2 x},
\qquad (\text{Re}\ s>0)
$$
where the convergence condition may be extended to $\text{Re}\ s>-1$, 
although we need not such extention now.

By putting $s=1/2$, we have an integral representation of $\zeta(1/2)$: 
$$
\zeta(1/2)=-(\sqrt{2}+1)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}\ \text{d}x}{\text{cosh}^2\ x},
$$
which can be numerically integrated accurately such as the double exponential method of Mori-Takahashi. The result is
$$
\zeta(1/2)=-1.460354508809586\cdots,
$$
which is our final result.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) :

$\zeta(s)=\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty}(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s} -\frac{N^{1-s}}{1-s})$ ;for $\Re(s)>0$ and $\Re(s)\ne 1$.

By putting **s=1/2** , we get:

$\zeta(1/2)=\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty}(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -2\sqrt{N})$

This series converges very slowly

(I got for N=14000 the result $\zeta(1/2)\approx -1.45613 $ which still away from $\approx -1.46035$)

Answer (score 2):

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^s}$$
**only when $\textbf{Real part}\mathbf{(s) > 1}$**. For the rest of $s$, in the complex plane, it is defined as the analytic continuation of the above function.

Answer (score 1):

No. The formula $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}$ is only valid for $\Re s>1$. The function is defined for other values of $s$ by [analytic continuation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi9gMKRhKzKAhXGOCYKHdztAhMQjBAIKjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAnalytic_continuation&usg=AFQjCNGZeKwUEOqlGKpZYa94NQsfsDz_RQ), using the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation).